# Is flirting still widely used?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

It seems to me that **flirting** was being used way more than it is used now like 10 years ago. Of course, my data is solely based on my web searches. But are there any recent alternatives? Does it feel weird when somebody uses the term flirt?

Comment: In what context would you use this word?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of the language, not its usage.

Comment: @MikeBrockington No, it isn't. It's a valid question about the usage of a word in Present-Day English. However, appropriateness ("does it feel weird") depends on register, whether it's writing or speech, etc. I'd actually say in this case the verb *flirt* is okay across registers, but some might well consider it somewhat old-fashioned. I'm not a native speaker, so I don't know. What I do know is that there are thousands of words and idioms that it's so unlikely you won't make a mistake in that sense if you're a non-native speaker. As long as the other person can understand you, you're good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten years ago, the word "flirt" was being used in books and journals more and more. Usually you would expect such a trend to continue.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flirt%2Charass&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3

It is possible that there has been a change more recently, as "flirting" has been assumed to be a euphemism for "sexual harassment". People could be avoiding the word, as it has these negative connotations.

Ngrams doesn't have data on the more recent books, and it has never been a record of the spoken language. The trouble is, any other word that could be an alternative would also have the same connotations.

So you can use "flirt", but be aware that not everyone enjoys unwanted flirting, and you can't assume that everyone will have a postive attitude towards the behaviour described by the word.

Comment: Is "Unsually" supposed to be "Usually" or "Unusually"? That sentence isn't grammatical anyway. Is "would would" supposed to be "you would" or "one would"?